# Passing an image from one view to other iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I have 2 `UIViewController`s in my app.

1. In the **1st** `viewController`, i have a `UIButton` in a toolbar.
2. When i click on the button, it displays me a `UIActionSheet` to select whether to take a picture from camera or from gallery.
3. When i choose, for example, taking picture from gallery and i choose a picture, it displays the picture in the 1st `viewController`.

What i want is to take a picture from gallery photos or from camera and to go to the **2nd** `viewController` and display the image in the **2nd** `viewController`.

I searched a lot and tried so much codes but it doesn't work.

Here is the code of `ViewController.m`

```
- (IBAction)PictureButton:(UIButton *)sender {   
    NSLog(@"Click button take picture in toolbar view 1");

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Photo" 
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Picture From Camera", @"Picture From Gallery", nil];
    [actionSheet setTag:1001];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
 }

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    switch (buttonIndex)
    {
        case 0: {
            // Take a picture from camera
            UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            picker.delegate = self;
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        }
        break;
        case 1: {
            // take a picture from gallery photos

            UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            picker.delegate = self;
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
            [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
            [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        }
        break;
 }

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
 }
```

---

In my second view i created a `UIImageView` here is my code in `SecondViewController.h`

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageButton;
@end
```

Can You help me please.
Sorry for my bad English and thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to select image at `FirstViewController` and display it in `SecondViewContoller`. However, you did not do anything to switch to `SecondViewController` and pass your selected image to it in `ViewController.m`.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    secondViewController.imageButton.image = image;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response , i change the code by ours now it returns always to the First View and doesn't display any image.

Comment: You mean the imagePicker always return to the FirstView??

Comment: when i pick a picture from galery photos it returns to the First View as before and it doesn't display the image that i choose. The problem that it doesn't go to the second view it returns always to first View. thanks

Comment: where you imagePicker show in ? 1st view or 2nd View? the UIImagePickerController return to where you show it.

Comment: it doesn't show in first view and i can't access to second view because i m always returning to first view , here is a link to my project , i upload it , thanks so much for your help . http://www.mediafire.com/download/y0nwyqg0sdfwe7w/testProject.rar

Comment: I download your project but it's full of messy code , could you upload your code in .zip file?

Comment: it is ok with the link?

Comment: Here is the mediafire link http://www.mediafire.com/download/uygb1bods1takiy/TestProject.zip and here is a mega link : https://mega.co.nz/#!U44CnaSY!BCPoxR8gZo_chZiPwpQU1Qsmq6NIrQgSzf_4UoD-9Io  , please tell me if there is a problem with the link, sorry and thanks

Comment: it is ok with the link?

Comment: Your link is ok, and after i unzip it i got this error `could not read data from /Documents/TestProject 2/FantaProject/TestProject-Info.plist': The file “TestProject-Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file `

Comment: Here is the new link , http://www.mediafire.com/download/cbd36zf4wcqbe2o/test.zip or https://mega.co.nz/#!dwY0XIrD!JjZ4VU5LdknhpeOaxy3PXWq9m9UfW7v10Q0WC91Tivs . thanks

Comment: it is ok with tthe link?

Comment: Hi @user3162198 , Your link is good , and after i fixed some linker error and plist error. There are still a lot problem in your project.Here is two suggestion .1. Your code didn't work because you don't link your IBOutlet and IBAction to your storyboard.so you should fix that first. 2.My code won't work in stroyboard.you have to create a segue in stroyboard and use `performSegueWithIdentifier` to trigger the push action.